# What happens in the CPU if I pop / push all the stack?

Tags: assembly, arm, stack-memory, stack-pointer

I am doing an energy profile of an ARM processor for an academic project. I managed to measure the power consumption of several assembly instructions by running them in a ~200 insts loop, e.g.:

```
.rept 200  
add r1, r2, r3
.endr
```

However, when coming to stack instructions, I wondered: what happens if I do something like this?

```
.rept 200  
pop {r1}
.endr
```

Notice that the control flow isn't affected, since the loop uses an absolute jump at the end, and the code is running bare metal, without an OS.

**What happens when the stack finishes?** Does the `sp` simply overflow and wrap around, going to `0x00000000` and starting popping from there?

My power sensor doesn't see anything strange; it is a constant power drain like any other instruction. Then, the question also arises: what if I keep pushing instead?

Comment: The stack pointer is just a register.  So yeah, it'll just overflow eventually.  Though it's more likely that your code generates an exception when attempting to access undefined memory.  There might also be some sort of stack underflow protection kicking in (depends on CPU model).

Comment: Since there's no OS running, can an exception occur? The CPU is a Cortex-M4 (ARMv7 iirc).

Comment: Of course.  Exceptions are something the hardware does automatically.  I'm not even sure if `CPSID` would turn them off.

Comment: There are alternatives to `push` and `pop`.  Such as `ldr r1, [sp,#4]!` and  `ldr r1, [sp], #4`.  You can substitute another register for 'sp'.  Also, you can save 'sp' on the routine entry and point it to an array of know size.  An issue is that the power consumption may include the memory access (DDR/SRAM,internal SRAM, bus type, etc).  Also, the forms of the instructions maybe consume more/less power.  Especially consult TRM for cycle time advice as the extra cycles will often consume more power as well.

Comment: IF you keep popping you'll have logical stack underflow, but whether this is detected by the hardware depends on the specifics of the processors and the operating environment.  If you keep pushing, you'll have logical stack overflow, with the same above caveats about detection, however, unlike popping, pushing writes to memory so on some systems that don't detect overflow, you have the potential to wipe out all your data, and even your code when the machine keeps the code in the same address space memory as data.

Comment: @artlessnoise I need to actually test *that* instruction, because I need to create a profile at instruction-level (i.e., mapping a binary instruction to a energy cost). I need to estimate how much a *compiled* program will consume, and thus I cannot force equivalent instructions. @erikeidt thanks, I think popping is safe then, since this can't possibly overwrite the `.text` segment. OTHH, pushing may be a problem, I need to design an equivalent routine for that and estimate the cost indirectly.

Comment: There is nothing magical about a pop instruction.  It is equivalent to a load combined with an add of 4 to the stack pointer, and you can deduce its effect by thinking about it that way.  It will succeed as long as the stack pointer points to valid, mapped, accessible memory.  If it doesn't, the pop instruction will fault as any other load instruction would.  Likewise, the add can overflow just like any other add, and the result is silent wraparound just as always.

Comment: Anyway, why not just do something like: make sure the stack is at least N bytes large (for some large N), execute pop N/4 times, subtract N from the stack pointer, loop.  It just needs one additional cheap `sub` instruction, once every N/4 iterations, which should not significantly affect your measurements.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks! I'll try to come up to a test and I'll report (maybe in an answer)

Comment: This was exactly another suggestion I had.  **Also, you can save 'sp' on the routine entry and point it to an array of know size.**.  I understand that the `pop` variant **may** differ.  However, you also completely ignore that fact that what memory is the target of the `push` and `pop` may also affect power consumption.  Really, I think that the encoding efficiency of `pop` is the the only gain.  For some thumb register, you can use probably use `ldr` and the power will be the same.  But measuring is always instructive.  You don't know either or what is the point of measuring it?